# ui.bootstrap breaks my unit tests with unexpected results error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ui.bootstrap

In the controller I've used ui.bootstrap to implement pagination on my page, after installing ui.bootstrap I got following error message on my unit tests

[image: After using ui.bootstrap I got following error message]

Here is my Test file:

```
'use strict';

describe('LoginCtrl', function () {

  beforeEach(module('taxihomeFrontendApp'));

  var LoginCtrl,
    scope;

  var $httpBackend = {};

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _$httpBackend_) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    LoginCtrl = $controller('LoginCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));

  afterEach(function () {
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
    $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
  });

  it('should fail authentication', function(){
    var credentials = {'username':'badDriver', 'password':'1234'};
    $httpBackend.
      whenPOST('http://localhost:3000/login', credentials).
      respond(403, {error: 'not allowed'});
    scope.credentials = {
      username: 'badDriver',
      password: '1234'
    };
    scope.login(scope.credentials);
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(scope.error).toEqual('Something went wrong not allowed');
  });

});
```

My Karma config

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2015-04-23 using
// generator-karma 0.9.0

module.exports = function(config) {
  'use strict';

  config.set({
    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '../',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      // bower:js
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
      'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
      'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      // endbower
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: [
      'PhantomJS'
    ],

    // Which plugins to enable
    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
    // proxies: {
    //   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
    // },
    // URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
    // urlRoot: '_karma_'
  });
};
```

I used yo angular to scaffold the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to mock GET request for template file:

```
$httpBackend.expectGET('views/login.html').respond('<div>something</div>');
```

Put it in `beforeEach` to in `it` section.

Comment: I received following Error message:
Error: Unexpected request: POST http://localhost:3000/login
Expected GET views/login.html

Comment: Thanks I fixed it $httpBackend.expectGET instead I used $httpBackend.whenGET and it solved the issue